# How to create a UTF8 File in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

As per question how to i create a a file that also includes the Byte Order Mark?

Having some trouble displaying some chars because the csv viewer cannot display the chars correctly without the BOM.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT To Include code:

```
string attachment = string.Format("attachment; filename=results_{0}_to _{1}.csv", startDate.ToString("MM_yy_yyyy"), endDate.ToString("MM_yy_yyyy"));
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

string content = GetTextFromDB();

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(content);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Post the code you currently have - how are your writing the file out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be done automatically for any of the inbuilt code using an `Encoding`, such as `StreamWriter` - just make sure that the encoder you pass in is configured to include a bom (the default `Encoding.UTF8` includes the bom).

If you are handling your own `Encoding` -> `Stream` logic, then you need to call `.GetPreamble()` and write those bytes at the start of the stream.

The default `Encoding.UTF8` includes the preamble; but you can do it explicitly in the ctor: `new UTF8Encoding(true)`